# Playframework's Secure module is not redirecting to the original url after login

Tags: playframework

**Edited:**

*I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and this problem seems to occur on Chrome (7.0.517.44), however, everything works fine on Firefox.*

*This is extremely strange. I have another application where the redirectToOriginalUrl works fine in 'dev' mode on both browsers, but does not work in 'prod' mode (again on both browsers). Wow, I don't have the faintest idea what is happening!*

**The Problem:**

I am getting the strangest error with Playframework (version 1.1.1), where the redirectToOriginalURL is not working in the Secure module.

I have 2 controllers Application.java and NameC.java

The view Application/index.html displays a simple page with a link to an action in NameC.java (NameC.index())

NameC.java is protected with the annotation @With(Secure.class)

Here is the flow I am expecting. First the user goes to the application home page. There they click on the link which would take them to NameC.index. However, since NameC is protected with the Secure module, the user should be taken to the login form (since they are not yet logged in), and upon successful login, they should see the page rendered by NameC.index

I get the login form, but upon successful login, the user is taken to Application.index I tried putting a print statement in Secure.redirectToOriginalURL() method, and it seems like the "url" does not exist in flash scope.

Here is my code:

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
        render();
    }
}
```

**Application/index.html**

```
<a href="@{NameC.index()}">Click here</a>
```

**NameC.java**

```
@With(Secure.class)
public class NameC extends Controller {
    public static void index() {
    render();
    }
}
```

**NameC/index.html**

```
You should see this after a successful login.
<a href="@{Secure.logout()}">logout</a>
```

I am sure I am missing something very basic... can anyone please help me figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Could we see your implementation of Secure? Are you sure, you are not redirecting, overriding some method?

Comment: @Zenklys I have not changed anything in Secure.java I just tried running everything again and realized that this works fine on Firefox, but fails on Chrome (7.0.517.44). I am running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Check out browser console/inspector (Firebug & chrome inspector) in order to see if something went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original URL should be stored in the flash scope within the `login` function. If you are running an unmodified version of the Secure module, there should be a line of code like this:

```
flash.keep("url");
```

Data stored in flash scope is only available for the next request, then it is cleared. Contents of the flash scope are not stored in the server but in a cookie, so you should be able to see a cookie named PLAY_FLASH containing your original URL if you investigate the request with Firebug or similar too. If, for some reason, the cookie is not present, there is your problem.

Next, your `authenticate` function should (upon successful authentication) call the `redirectToOriginalURL` method which tries to retrieve the original URL from the flash scope (as you said) like this:

```
String url = flash.get("url");
```

If the URL is no longer available in the flash scope, most likely explanation is that another request has been made in between the `login` and `authenticate` requests, clearing the stored value from the flash scope. Again, Firebug will easily reveal if this is the reason - just have a look at the Net tab to see all network traffic taking place.

Comment: Yes indeed another request was being made as an AJAX call. This was a request for a generated image, so I could not see it in the HTML tab in the 'NET' section of Firebug. Thanks, for the help.

Answer (score 0):

redirectTo uses 301 status. It is not supposed to work differently on any browser but still. That can happen...