# In Play! 2.0 with Security trait how do I redirect to the original URL after login?

Tags: authentication, playframework-2.0

With Play! framework 2.0, using the [Security Trait](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaSecurity):

If I let users browse to several parts of the site unauthenticated, but on certain actions they need to authenticate, how do I redirect them to their original url before authentication and not the same url for all?

It is a similar requirement to this question for Play! 1.x [Playframework's Secure module is not redirecting to the original url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469312/playframeworks-secure-module-is-not-redirecting-to-the-original-url-after-login).

However the flash parameter for the original url is not available in 2.0 as far as I can tell.

Basicaly the change I am looking for would be in the **authenticate** method handler

```
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
    loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors)),
      user => Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession(Security.username -> user._1)
    )
  }
```

Where some sort of **Redirect(originalRequestUrl)** would be handy.

Any ideas for a clean solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `Referer` header, or explicitly carry the *return url* in your authenticate action:

## Using the `Referer` header

```scala
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(html.login(errors)),
    user => {
      val returnUrl = request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse(routes.Application.index.url)
      Redirect(returnUrl).withSession(Security.username -> user._1)
    }
}
```

## Carrying explicitly the return url

```scala
def authenticate(returnUrl: String) = Action { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest(html.login(errors, returnUrl)),
    user => Redirect(returnUrl).withSession(Security.username -> user._1)
  )
}
```

By using the `Referer` HTTP header you still have to handle the case where the browser doesn’t fill this header, and by carrying explicitly the return url as a parameter of your `authenticate` action you may have more boilerplate in your code handling with authentication…